Differentiation in the vector sense and Sobolev spaces.
In my book, there is a property that follows directly from the definition of the Sobolev spaces that is unclear. Here is the background.
$$
W_{1}^{p} =\{f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R^n}) : \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a}f - f}{\varepsilon} = - D_{a}f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\;\text{for all } a\in\mathbb{R}^n \}
$$
where $(\tau_{z}f)(x) = f(x-z)$.
This definition does not hurt the intuition, but I do not see how to prove the following property :
Let $a=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k}e_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\in W_{1}^{p}$, then $D_{a}f = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a^k D_{e_k}f$.
The fact that $\tau_{a^1 + a^2}f = (\tau_{a^1}\circ\tau_{a^2})f$ is blocking me in all the proof I attempt. Do you have any hint please ?
Thank you.

This edit is just to ensure that I have well understood the answer given by LL 3.14.
Let $\varepsilon\neq 0$, using the fact that $\tau_{a^1 + a^2}f = (\tau_{a^1}\circ\tau_{a^2})f$ we should observe that
$$
\tau_{\varepsilon(a^1 + a^2)}f - f = \tau_{\varepsilon a^1}(\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f) - f = \tau_{\varepsilon a^1}(\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f) - \tau_{\varepsilon a^1}f + \tau_{\varepsilon a^1}f - f
$$
Using the linearity of the translation map $\tau_{a}$ and dividing by $\varepsilon$ we get
$$
\frac{\tau_{\varepsilon(a^1 + a^2)}f - f}{\varepsilon} = \tau_{\varepsilon a^1}\left(\frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f - f}{\varepsilon}\right) + \frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^1}f - f}{\varepsilon}
$$
To conclude, we need to prove that $\tau_{\varepsilon a^1}\left(\frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f - f}{\varepsilon}\right)$ converges to $-D_{a^2}f$ as $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$. It's clear that $\tau_{\varepsilon}$ converges (in $L^p$ norm) to the identity map as $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$. Let $\eta>0$, by the last sentence, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $0<\varepsilon<\delta_1$ or $-\delta_1<\varepsilon<0$ implies
$$
\left\lVert \tau_{\varepsilon a^1}\left(\frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f - f}{\varepsilon}\right) - \frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f - f}{\varepsilon} \right\rVert_{L^p}<\frac{\eta}{2}
$$
Using the definition of the differentiation with the point $a^2$ we get the existence of $\delta_2>0$ such that $0<\varepsilon<\delta_2$ or $-\delta_2<\varepsilon<0$ implies
$$
\left\lVert \frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f - f}{\varepsilon} + D_{a^2}f\right\rVert_{L^p}<\frac{\eta}{2}
$$
Hence, by letting $\delta=\min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$, we get an open neighborhood of $0$, $N(0)$ (that does not contains $0$) such that for all $\varepsilon\in N(0)$ we have
$$
\left\lVert \tau_{\varepsilon a^1}\left(\frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f - f}{\varepsilon}\right) + D_{a^2}f \right\rVert_{L^p}\leq \left\lVert \tau_{\varepsilon a^1}\left(\frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f - f}{\varepsilon}\right) - \frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f - f}{\varepsilon} \right\rVert_{L^p} + \left\lVert \frac{\tau_{\varepsilon a^2}f - f}{\varepsilon} + D_{a^2}f\right\rVert_{L^p}$$
$$<\frac{\eta}{2} + \frac{\eta}{2}=\eta\;\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{.}$$
Which proves the claim. The conclusion about the linearity of the map that associates to each $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ the element $D_{a}f\in L^{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (when $f\in W_{1}^{p}$) follows directly.

As written, this is false even with $n=1$, since $D_{-1}=D_1\neq -D_1$. And even more, as defined $D_af$ is a number independent of $x\in\Bbb R^n$, but you indicate that it should be in $L^p(\Bbb R^n)$ ... so it is a function? Please review your post

@LL3.14 Very sorry about the nonsense in the definition of $W_{1}^{p}$, it should be correct now.

I think (let me know if not) that the question is acceptable now so if the downvote could be removed please.

If $a=a_1 + a_2$ then just use $\tau_{\epsilon a} = \tau_{\epsilon a_1}\tau_{\epsilon a_2}$ to get
$$
\tau_{\epsilon a}f - f = \tau_{\epsilon a_1}(\tau_{\epsilon a_2}f - f) + \tau_{\epsilon a_1}f - f
$$
and since $\tau_{\epsilon a_1}\to \mathrm{Id}$, one gets as $\epsilon \to 0$ (tell me if you need more details here)
$$
\frac{\tau_{\epsilon a}f - f}{\epsilon} \to D_{a_2}f + D_{a_1}f
$$

Thank you a lot for the answer ! Indeed, I (really) should remember that the operator $\tau_a$ is linear ! I tried to fill in the details by editing my post, let me know if I am wrong please
